# How to use App ID in Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am new to `xamarin` and Visual Studio, and after creating my app in `xamarin` Android(not FORMS) I want to place ads.

My problem is that I am using Google.Mobile.Ads `nuget`, and I found some examples that I can use but none of those examples uses App ID and I am not sure why. Every tutorial is half explained and I am really stuck , and my question is the following:

Does that nuget do not need the App ID and use just the Banner Id or I am looking at wrong examples ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does that nuget do not need the App ID and use just the Banner Id or I am looking at wrong examples?

Normally, when we place ads, we need "App Id" and "Unit Id". Both of them generated by registring with AdMob.

https://apps.admob.com

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-google-admob/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/monetize-your-app-using-google-admob/

Tutorial about how to place ads in Xamarin.android.

https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-android/

You could download android code sample here.

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/google-services/AdMobExample

[image]