# Which package should I use to embed admob in xamarin-forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, admob

I was thinking to use the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite package https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6teJvSCg6UA&t=661s
But I can't find up-to-date instruction for embedding admob in xamarin-forms.

I registered with admob but found instructions only for kotlin and java.

Which package is currently relevant for xamarin-forms? And is there an up-to-date implementation guide?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a control and do that with custom renderer.

Custom control:

```
public class AdControlView : View
{
}
```

Custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdControlView), typeof(AdViewRenderer))]
namespace App14.Droid
{
public class AdViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdControlView, AdView>
{
    public AdViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    string adUnitId = string.Empty;
    //Note you may want to adjust this, see further down.
    AdSize adSize = AdSize.Banner;
    AdView adView;
    AdView CreateNativeAdControl()
    {
        if (adView != null)
            return adView;

      
        adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"; //you could create you own unit id.
        adView = new AdView(Forms.Context);
        adView.AdSize = adSize;
        adView.AdUnitId = adUnitId;

        var adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);

        adView.LayoutParameters = adParams;

        adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest
                        .Builder()
                        .Build());
        return adView;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdControlView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
        {
            CreateNativeAdControl();
            SetNativeControl(adView);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Create your own application id and unitid or you could get the test ads on Google Admob.

For more details, please refer to the case i done before.
[How to use App ID in Xamarin Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58580463/how-to-use-app-id-in-xamarin-visual-studio/58586436#58586436)